# Why is my date field being returned into R from SQL database as a double etc

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, dbplyr

Testing out dbplyr and connection to database and am getting dates returned as a double

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

df.in <- data.frame(count = c(1:2),Date = as.Date(rep(0,2), origin = "1900-
01-01"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df.in)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ count: int  1 2
#  $ Date : Date, format: "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"

DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "df.in", df.in, overwrite=TRUE)
df.out<- dplyr::tbl(con, "df.in") 
str(df.out)
# List of 2
#  $ src:List of 2
#   ..$ con  :Formal class 'SQLiteConnection' [package "RSQLite"] with 6 
slots
#   .. .. ..@ ptr                :<externalptr> 
#   .. .. ..@ dbname             : chr ":memory:"
#   .. .. ..@ loadable.extensions: logi TRUE
#   .. .. ..@ flags              : int 70
#   .. .. ..@ vfs                : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ ref                :<environment: 0x00000000137b7dc0> 
#   ..$ disco: NULL
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "src_dbi" "src_sql" "src"
#  $ ops:List of 2
#   ..$ x   :Classes 'ident', 'character'  chr "df.in"
#   ..$ vars: chr [1:2] "count" "Date"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_base_remote" "op_base" "op"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "tbl_dbi" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"

df.out
# Source:   table<df.in> [?? x 2]
# Database: sqlite 3.19.3 [:memory:]
#   count   Date
#   <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1 -25567
# 2     2 -25567
```

a) df.out is a list. What is the best way to see the underlying data being returned i.e. count and Date in  a data.frame or tbl format

b) Why is a double being returned rather than a date

c) As I am hitting this problem , I have been unable to replicate my initial issue (with an MS SQL server connection)  which was that when using dplyr code on data  - where gameDate has been confirmed as a Date field - to do a mutation I get this error

```
df.out %>%
  mutate(month=months(gameDate))

# nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 
11.0][SQL Server]'MONTHS' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Is there anyway around this. I thought dbplyr translated the dplyr code into appropriate SQL

TIA for help on any of above points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because, as of today, the `months()` vector function does not have a translation for MSSQL in `dbplyr` yet.  The nice part how `dplyr` translations work is that it will let you call a database native command, in MSSQL, the DATENAME function should do what you need. This code should work:

`df.out %>%
  mutate(month=datename(month, gameDate))`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm no expert in SQL connections but Couple of points a) isn't this an SQLiteConnection? b) when i do set up a connection to an MSSQL :Formal class 'Microsoft SQL Server' The code runs without error with your amendment but then when I run df.out I get this error Error: <SQL> 'SELECT  TOP 1000 "count", "Date", DATENAME('month', "gameDate") AS "month"
FROM "df.in"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid parameter 1 specified for datename.

Comment: Right, it is not a SQLite connection, I focused on your original issue which is the date conversion in MS SQL.  I think quoting month is the problem when you run df.in.  Let's try this:   df.out %>% mutate(month=datename(month, gameDate))

Comment: Thanks that works. Not sure of protocol. Should i edit your answer or will you do it   Also, is there a list of other functions available which have yet to be translated for MSSQL and an estimated time when it will be seamless. That would help me decide on whether to shelve a project for a while or not

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I just fixed it in the original comment. The best way to see a list of what's available today is to take a look at the actual code, here's the link to the MSSQL translation in `dbplyr`: https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/master/R/db-odbc-mssql.R

Comment: Thanks for link. I just tried head() and tail(), for instance. Former ok latter not. I'll just run my code and see how it goes